# EntityManager.merge() persistindo ao invés de atualizar

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Método update:

```java
public void update(T u) {
    EntityManagerFactory f = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("crud");
    EntityManager em = f.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(u);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    f.close();
}
```

Estive usando esse mesmo método e estava funcionando perfeitamente. Agora, ao invés de atualizar o estado da entidade ele persiste um novo registro todas as vezes que tento atualizar. Já tentei o `update()` da session e obtive o mesmo resultado.

Comment: A entidade está com a PK setada?

Comment: Sim , dei um syso antes de invocar o merge() e a PK é != null

Comment: Minha suspeita é de que quando dou o submit no meu form de editar ele chama o setId() de alguma forma. Como não pus um inputText para o meu atributo id ele seta pra 0. Digo isso pois depois do submit o id vai pra 0. Estou esquecendo algo ?

Comment: Como suspeitei, inclui um inputHidden no form com value da id e deu update normal. Esse cara me deu a dica [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837833/jpa-persisting-instead-of-updating)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Objeto vs. Entidade

Ao trabalharmos com JPA/Hibernate é importante ter em mente que um objeto qualquer, mesmo sendo instância de uma classe anotada com `@Entity` ou mapeada num XML, não é automaticamente uma *entidade JPA*.

Isso significa que não importa se a PK está devidamente preenchida, um objeto não é uma *entidade* se não está *gerenciado* num *contexto de persistência* (*persistent context*).

## Estados JPA

Vejamos um diagrama de estados simplificado do JPA ([fonte](http://gerrydevstory.com/2012/05/21/various-states-of-jpa-entities/)):

[image: diagrama de estados JPA]

Quanto criamos uma instância do objeto ele está no estado *novo* (***new***). Ao chamarmos o método `persist` nosso objeto passa a ser uma *entidade gerenciada* (***managed***), embora o registro provavelmente não seja inserido no banco de dados até o `commit`.

Após o encerramento do context do JPA (`commit` da transação, `close` do `EntityManager` ou método `detach`), nossa entidade entrará no estado ***detached***. Posteriormente poderemos trazê-la novamente para o contexto de persistência do JPA com o método `merge`.

Se excluirmos uma entidade com o método `remove` ela entrará no estado *removida* (***removed***) e até o fim da transação um comando `DELETE` será enviado ao banco de dados. Se quisermos persistir a entidade novamente, podemos chamar o método `persist`.

## Como funciona o `merge`

Agora que entendemos os estados das entidades, vejamos agora como funciona o método `merge`. Eis um diagrama muito interessante ([fonte](http://spitballer.blogspot.de/2010/04/jpa-persisting-vs-merging-entites.html)):

[image: algoritmo do merge]

- O primeiro passo do `merge` é verificar se a entidade está no estado *gerenciado* (***managed***), pois em caso afirmativo a própria entidade é retornada.
- Se a entidade foi removida (***removed***) um erro é lançado.
- Se o contexto de persistência já possui uma versão dessa entidade, ela será atualizada com o estado do objeto passado por parâmetro e então será retornada.
- Se não há uma entidade equivalente, verifica-se se esta é uma nova entidade:

  - Se for, cria-se uma nova instância (equivalente ao `persist`).
  - Se **não** for, carrega-se a entidade no contexto de persistência a partir do banco de dados.

## Um erro comum ao usar `merge`

Note que o principal objetivo do método `merge` é devolver uma entidade JPA gerenciada pelo contexto de persistência.

Se o objeto passado por parâmetro não for uma entidade JPA, o mesmo **não** será incluído no contexto de persistência, mas uma cópia será feita e retornada pelo método `merge`.

Como descrito [nesta famosa questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge), um erro comum é esperar que o objeto passado para o método torne-se uma entidade.

#### Incorreto

```java
MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
em.merge(e);
e.setAtributo(novoValor);
```

No exemplo acima, alterar o valor do objeto original não afeta o estado da entidade JPA criada pelo `merge`.

#### Correto

```java
MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
MyEntity e2 = em.merge(e);
e2.setAtributo(novoValor);
```

Já neste exemplo, o valor será atualizado no banco de dados pois a entidade gerenciada retornada pelo `merge` foi modificada.

## Voltando ao problema da pergunta

Com toda a teoria em mente podemos concluir que o método `merge` irá incluir uma nova entidade e, consequentemente, um novo registro no banco de dados, quando o objeto passado para o método for considerado uma *nova entidade*.

Em quais cenários isto é possível? Não posso prever todos, mas eis os mais comuns:

- A PK é um valor sequencial (`@GeneratedValue`) e não está devidamente preenchida, gerando assim uma nova entrada no banco de dados.
- Há uma coluna de versão (`@Version`) que não está devidamente preenchida no banco de dados ([ver esta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5156430/1683070)).
- Existe um relacionamento com outra entidade e, por alguma razão, o JPA está gerando uma query com `INNER JOIN` entre as duas tabelas e não encontra resultados devido à ausência de registros na outra tabela, chegando à conclusão de que a entidade principal não existe. [Este artigo](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.de/2010/12/jpa-insert-instead-of-update.html) trata do assunto com relação a uma anotação do EclipseLink, mas isso pode ocorrer no Hibernate de algumas formas, por exemplo, via [herança](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity).

## Uma alternativa

Outra forma de usar o `merge` é recuperar a entidade gerenciada e alterá-la conforme necessário.

Exemplo:

```java
MyEntity e = //entidade criada em algum outro lugar (JSF, Spring, etc.)
MyEntity e2 = em.find(MyEntity.class, idEntidade);
e.setAtributo(e.getAtributo);
```

Embora atualizar os atributos individualmente seja mais "trabalhoso" e faça o código ficar maior, isso evita que a "mágica" dos frameworks ou mesmo a manipulação indevida de atributos acabe gerando efeitos não esperados no banco de dados.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação!

Answer (score 0):

Remover a antiga entidade e persistir a nova também funciona.

```html
public void update(T u) {
    EntityManagerFactory f = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("crud");
    EntityManager em = f.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(u.getID())
    em.persist(u);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    f.close();
}
```