# Diferença entre Merge() e getInstace() no JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Gostaria de saber quando devo utilizar `merge()` para atualizar o objeto ao invés de alterá-lo através de sua referência.

Exemplo:

```
Produto p = new Produto();
p.setNome("Bola");
p.setvalor("32);
manager.persist(p);
manager.getTransation().begin();
manager.getTransation().commit();
```

#### Atualizando com `merge()`

```
Produto p2 = p;
p2.setNome("Bola Editado");
manager.merge(p2);
manager.getTransation().commit();
```

#### Atualizando com `getInstance()`

```
Produto p2 = manager.getReference(Produto.class, p.getId());
p2.setNome("Bola Editado")
manager.getTransation().begin();
manager.getTransation().commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

O `merge()` recebe um objeto "comum", que não está no contexto de persistência, e copia as propriedades deste objeto para a verdadeira instância da entidade. Use-o quando você não quer recuperar a entidade e alterar seus atributos manualmente.

## Objetos vs. Entidades e o funcionamento do JPA

O primeiro passo para compreender melhor como funciona o JPA é entender exatamente como ele trata as entidades e os estados que esses objetos podem assumir.

Para isso, sugiro que leia [minha outra resposta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6270/227).

## Usando o `merge`

Basicamente, o `merge()` recebe um objeto criado fora do JPA, seja diretamente no seu código ou em algum processo automático como algum *JSON deserializer* ou um framework MVC que mapeia o *request* para um *Java Bean*.

Ao receber este objeto, o JPA verifica se já existe uma instância no contexto ou então recupera uma a partir da base de dados.

Depois ele pega os valores da instância que você passou e atribui para a instância do contexto de persistência, efetivamente atualizando os dados da entidade verdadeira. Note que ele vai atualizar todos os atributos e não somente os que possuem valor.

Então o método `merge()` retorna para você a entidade atualizada. Neste ponto, o objeto que você passou para ele pode ser descartado.

## Quando usar o `getReference()`

O `getReference()` retorna um *proxy* para uma entidade que está no banco de dados. Os dados não são carregados do banco imediatamente, a não ser a chave primária. Esse *proxy* funciona como um objeto *lazy* que só vai carregar os atributos da entidade quando você chamar algum método `getter`.

Enfim, use esse método quando você quer evitar carregar muitos dados do banco desnecessariamente, como em casos em que você vai usar apenas um ou dois campos de uma entidade apenas se uma determinada condição for satisfeita ou quando você precisar passar uma entidade como parâmetro e possivelmente ela não é usada dentro do método receptor.

Enfim, a vantagem é postergar a transferência de dados que você provavelmente não vai usar. A desvantagem é que, se for usar os dados, o "custo" é maior já que vai ter que fazer mais consultas ao banco.

Sinceramente, nunca vi necessidade real do uso desse método.

## Quando usar o `find()`

O método `find()` também retorna uma entidade, porém já com os dados carregados, exceto é claro relacionamentos *lazy*.

## Considerações

Para **recuperar** uma entidade, o método `find()` quase sempre é o que você vai precisar. Use o `find()` por padrão e, se tiver problemas de desempenho, então verifique qual outro método pode ajudar.

Para **atualizar** uma entidade, use o `merge()` quando você já tem um objeto populado com todos os novos valores que seja gravar no banco.

Para **atualizações parciais**, use o `find()` ou `getReference()` e o respectivo `setter` da propriedade que deseja atualizar.