# Enviar pelo jsp um comando para o controller atualizar através de metodo o banco de dados

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

Eu quero fazer um "deposito" na conta com Id "x". O controller envia a "conta" para o jsp que devolve o valor do deposito para ser atualizado no banco de dados. Essa foi a lógica que usei, mas acho que errei em algo, acredito que no JSP ou no Controller. Pois ao clicar em "depositar" vai para a pagina seguinte como se tivesse ocorrido tudo bem mas o BD não é atualizado. 
Qual lógica eu deveria ter usado?

Edit 1: No inicio estava ocorrendo o erro "detached entity passed to persist: br.com.bitbank.modelo.Cliente" utilizando "persist". Pesquisei um pouco e por mais que o "find" retorne uma Entity "maneged" o erro continuou, então troquei o comando para "merge". Não ocorre mais nenhum erro no console, mas a tabela "Conta" ganha mais um cadastro todo "NULL".

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| id | agencia | numero | saldo |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
|  1 |      10 |   4645 |     0 | Cadastro normal
|  2 |    NULL |   NULL |     0 | Após tentar "depositar"
```

O link do meu projeto completo: https://github.com/BryanMotta/FormacaoJava/tree/master/src/main/java/br/com/bitbank

As partes que estou modificando:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/transacao")

public class TransacaoController {

@Autowired
private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/deposita/{id}")
public ModelAndView form(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("transacao/transacao");

    Cliente cliente = clienteDAO.find(id);
    modelAndView.addObject("cliente", cliente);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deposita/{id}")
public ModelAndView deposita(@PathVariable("id") int id, Cliente cliente) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

    //Cliente cliente = clienteDAO.find(id);
    clienteDAO.atualiza(cliente);
    modelAndView.addObject("cliente", cliente);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form:form action="${s:mvcUrl('TC#deposita').arg(0,cliente.id).build() }" 
     method="post"
    modelAttribute="cliente">
    <div>
    <input type="number" name="conta.deposita" />        
    <button type="submit">Depositar</button>
    </div>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

DAO

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ClienteDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;

public void gravar(Cliente cliente) {
    manager.persist(cliente);
}
public void atualiza(Cliente cliente) {
    manager.merge(cliente);
}

public Cliente getProduto(Integer id) {
    Cliente cliente = manager.find(Cliente.class, id);
    return cliente;
}
public List<Cliente> listar() {
    return manager.createQuery("select c from Cliente c", Cliente.class)
            .getResultList();
}

public Cliente find(int id) {
    return manager.find(Cliente.class, id);
}
```

Comment: dá alguma exception?

Comment: Sim, utilizando "persist" da o erro "detached entity passed to persist: br.com.bitbank.modelo.Cliente", e utilizando "merge" não ocorre nenhum no console, mas a tabela conta ganha mais um cadastro todo "NULL".   Vou add essas informações na pergunta principal.

Comment: e a sua intenção é de fato inserir um novo estado ou apenas atualizar o original?

Comment: Atualizar o original. Quando eu faço o cadastro de um novo cliente automaticamente o saldo dele é setado como 0, o metodo deposita somaria um valor ao saldo.

Comment: entendi, é que persist e merge nao servem pra isso,  você comentou ali que quando recupera pelo find by id o objeto vem managed certo? nesse caso seria só alterar as informações desse objeto e dar um commit, talvez nem do commit precise se aquele transactional estiver funcionando

Comment: Acho que entendi, não preciso usar persist e merge no meu controller. Mas como faço a lógica para isso? É feita no jsp ou no controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu simplifiquei um pouco meu form no jsp e passei a enviar o id do cliente para ser modificado junto com o valor a ser depositado

```
<form:form action="${s:mvcUrl('TC#deposita').arg(0,cliente.id).build() }" 
method="post"
        modelAttribute="cliente">
        <div>
            Nome:${cliente.titular.nome} Id:${cliente.conta.id}
            <input type="number" name="deposita" />
            <form:hidden path="id" value="${cliente.id}"/>  
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Depositar</button>
    </form:form>
```

E no meu controller passei a usar WebRequest para pegar os parâmetros passados pelo jsp ficando dessa forma

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deposita/{id}") 
  public ModelAndView deposita(@PathVariable("id") int id, WebRequest request) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

    //pega o id enviado pelo form e da um find no cliente
    Cliente cliente =clienteDAO.find(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
    //pega o valor do deposisto enviado pelo form e chama o metodo da classe passadno 
    //esse valor 

   cliente.getConta().deposita(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("deposita")));
        //atualiza esse valor utilizando o merge
    clienteDAO.atualizar(cliente);      

    //modelAndView.addObject("cliente", cliente);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

E em relação ao Merge usei essa resposta como explicação

"Usando o merge
Basicamente, o merge() recebe um objeto criado fora do JPA, seja diretamente no seu código ou em algum processo automático como algum JSON deserializer ou um framework MVC que mapeia o request para um Java Bean.

Ao receber este objeto, o JPA verifica se já existe uma instância no contexto ou então recupera uma a partir da base de dados.

Depois ele pega os valores da instância que você passou e atribui para a instância do contexto de persistência, efetivamente atualizando os dados da entidade verdadeira. Note que ele vai atualizar todos os atributos e não somente os que possuem valor.

Então o método merge() retorna para você a entidade atualizada. Neste ponto, o objeto que você passou para ele pode ser descartado."

fonte:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60035/152788